# Regexp pattern for list of email

Tags: java, regex

I need valid regexp for email seperated by `" "` and ends with `@a.com` or `b.com`

for example:

valid email `string`: `"email1@a.com email2@b.com email3@a.com"`

invalid email `string`: `"email1@a.com email2@b.com email3@c.com"`

Comment: And what all your username before `@` can contain?

Comment: before can be anything  like in other valid mail

Comment: There are many other valid mails. Some allo underscores, some allow hyphen, some allow a dot. What you want?

Comment: And is your list of email separated by space?

Comment: yes email are separated bye space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
^(.*@(a|b).com(|\s)*$

[Permalink](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5E%28.%2a@%28a%7Cb%29.com%28%7C%5Cs%29%29%2a%24&input=asdsadsa@a.com%20asdsadsa@b.com%20asdsadsa@b.com%0A) - try entering an invalid string like "c.com" and see that it works too

[Regexpal](http://regexpal.com) is a nice easy tool to start working on making regex for whatever problem you are trying to solve!

Comment: Run what? Regexpal checks the regex/input and highlights as you type.

Answer (score 4):

I don't necessarily think a regexp is an extensible and maintainable solution here. I would rather:

1. split the list on whitespace (perhaps on whitespace preceeded by a .com/.org etc.)
2. extract the domain name post-@
3. compare this vs. a whitelist (or blacklist)

I like regexps a lot, but I don't always think they're the solution. See [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) for a discussion on this, and note the below!

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: Why not ? String.split(" ") would be a simple approach

Comment: because I am useing wicket pattern validator and value is this string. There isnt any possiblity to split it

Comment: I wouldn't use it then. Not being funny, but I don't think it's appropriate

Comment: @BrianAgnew `split` would not be a good option since space is allowed in email address

Comment: hm really space are allowed ? hm space is invalid char for my valid email.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this expression:

```
^(( |^)[^ @]+@[ab]\.com)+$
//  ^    ^   ^  ^    ^
//  |    |   |  |    +- The mandatory .com   
//  |    |   |  +------ Either a or b
//  |    |   +--------- An @ sign
//  |    +------------- Anything but space or @ repeated at least once
//  +----------------------- Preceded by a space or the beginning of line
```

Comment: I was not aware that `^` could be consumed more than once (makes sense though).

Answer (score 0):

`(email[1-3]\@[ab].com )*email[1-3]\@[ab].com` ?

(replace [1-3] and [ab] with whatever really suits you).

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+@[ab]\.com( [A-Za-z0-9_.-]+@[ab]\.com)*
```

You can change the `[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+` part if you want to be more restrictive.

Comment: The local part can contain much more than letters numbers and _.- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part

Comment: also, `.` can not be the first character.